# What does "グジュグジュ" mean?

Tags: translation, onomatopoeia

Found it here. https://www.hostfamily2012.com/3657.html

> コッカーのムーさん
>
> お耳の中、グジュグジュ・・汚れ改善したいですね！！
>
> お肌は大丈夫かなぁ～今日も大人しくできました～>^_^<
>
> カットもOKかなぁ～！！

I've tried looking it up in as many dictionary as I can find but I found nothing. Is this an onomatopoeia of some sort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「グジュグジュ」 is indeed an onomatopoeia describing something being wet, watery, damp, etc. (often, if not always, in a grubby way.)

Onomatopoeias often have multiple variants to them: therefore, many of them cannot be found in dictionaries.  We also say 「グチュグチュ」、「グショグショ」、「グチョグチョ」, etc.

Here, it is talking about the inside of a dog's ears by using the onomatopoeia.  This particular dog has wet discharge inside its ears, which is not ideal as that can help bacteria thrive in the ears.

So, the first two lines mean:

> "(As for) ムー the cocker spaniel.."
>
> "It is wet and grubby inside his ears.  Gotta do something to get rid of that, don't we? "

Answer (score 4):

グジュグジュ is a mimetic word that describes a wet and dirty/messy/sticky thing. Examples of グジュグジュな things include:

- handkerchief soaked with sweat
- face soaked with tear and snot
- rotten tomato
- infected wound